# Create line from origin to vertex of mesh in geometry nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, geometry-nodes

I want to create a line with the origin as starting point and the vertex of a circle line as final point
[image]

How can I do in geometry nodes? I tried to use the transfer attribute to capture each vertex but I didn't work.

That is my simple node for the circle:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Here's one approach]

This uses a transfer attribute node to get the position vector at a specific index.  It will also work if you use a mesh circle instead of the curve and you don't need the curve to mesh node.

I've made the circle radius and index both input parameters.  You do need some way to specify which vertex, after all.